# What can I do when I can't offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I recently started as an intern with a programming assignment for Android. I am not that good with Android yet so I have a lot of problems when I code. That's when I decided I should use Stack Overflow to find answers, and I did, a lot, but sometimes they don't help and I have to ask a question for myself.

These questions are not being viewed at all and I read about something called a bounty but I haven't acquired enough reputation to hand out bounties.

What should I do in this situation, just wait?

Comment: *"Just wait?"* - Yes....or answer questions on subject you have more familiarity with and gain the necessary reputation that way. Alternatively, interns are *suppposed* to ask their colleagues questions...try that.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's the funny part, I'm an intern and I have to make an Android app, but nobody here knows Android :p

Comment: Sounds like your company has good recruiting practices...

Comment: It's a school thing, they saw it as a "challenge", can't blame the company though, if I could get someone to make me something for free, I would take that chance.

Comment: You're not talking about the question you posted 3 hrs ago, are you? It seems your older questions are commented on and/or answered. That said: you are not doing *bad*, for an 18 day member. Change the title of your last question. Usually I'd also advise to take a good look at the tags you use, but that seems to be okay as well (being not a field expert).

Comment: I was mainly talking about my question from two days ago, I really need help with that one.

Comment: That would be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36033233/2564301)? I was thinking of setting a bounty on it (not unheard of - I'd even earn a badge for that) ... but can you give it a thorough edit? The "edit:"'s are obsolete, and your interjections and disclaimers make it hard to follow.

Comment: @RadLexus I'll take a good look at it and edit it when I can. At the moment I've taken peace with the fact that I can't solve it right away and I started working on a different part of the app. When I find some time, I'll give it a good edit and I'll give you a heads up about it. I'm pretty new to asking questions on this site so yeah, I can use a little practice in making said questions a little more clear.